# R 4.1.0 crashes when trying to ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, crash, rstudio

I updated to R 4.1.0 yesterday (19 May 2021) and initially everything was working fine, I just needed to reinstall all of my User Library packages. Now I am unable to make a simple ggplot.

```
library(ggplot2)
Cars <- mtcars
ggplot(Cars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
geom_point()
```

The ggplot line causes a whole bunch of `[21263:21263:20210520,162145.598752:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found` (see picture).

Looking around, this error is usually associated with nvidia graphics drivers. I have a GeForce2 with what I think is the newest driver (460) but even when I switch to my native Intel graphics driver I get the same error. Has anyone else experienced this yet? Should I revert back to R 3.6.3?

[image: screenshot of RStudio with "bomb"/"R Session Aborted" screen]

Comment: I should also add that this does not crash RStudio like in this post https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7310

Comment: This came up recently on Twitter, looks like you need dev version of RStudio (not tested): https://twitter.com/kevin_ushey/status/1395054942088400905

Comment: I think we can close this question (not delete), as there is no useful answer. Eventually, there will be a more stable version of RStudio with a fix for this bug.

Comment: I agree with that

Comment: I chose to answer the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638836/r-crashing-while-displaying-ggplot-after-update-process-memory-read-out-of-rang/67638944#67638944).  It will obviously be outdated eventually, but in the meantime (for the next few weeks) it will be useful for people trying to resolve this problem