# R crashing while displaying ggplot after update (process memory read out of range)

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I just updated to R 4.1.0 and re-installed my packages and Rstudio (on Ubuntu 20.04). Now R runs out of memory and crashes when I try to make any ggplot. The error message is long and I can't fully read it because the R session immediately aborts, but it mentions `"missing nul terminator"`, `"process memory read out of range"` and a bunch of lines of `[XXXX:XXXX:YYYYYYYY,ZZZZZZ,AAAAAA ERROR: elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found` and finally `[XXXX:XXXX:YYYYYYYY,ZZZZZZ,AAAAAA] ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir: No such file or directory (2)` (where X, Y, Z, and A are numbers).

I originally got this error with my data but it seems to happen with any ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = mpg)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I think it's to do with actually displaying the plot because it doesn't crash when I save the plot into a variable and then `ggsave()` it, and the resulting file is fine. It's also OK when I do `ggplot(...)` within a function with `ggsave()` in the next line.

The same plot in base R works fine.

```
boxplot(mpg~cyl, data = mtcars)
```

==> displays boxplot in the Plots pane

Reinstalling ggplot2 with `install.packages()` didn't fix the problem, and I tried to `sudo apt install ./rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb` again but it just says Rstudio is already the newest version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This [tweet from Kevin Ushey](https://twitter.com/kevin_ushey/status/1395054942088400905) says:

> PSA: If you're an RStudio user planning to upgrade to R 4.1.0, you may want to install the preview release of RStudio (https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) -- otherwise, you may see RStudio crash when you try to use ggplot2.

The version number is "1.4.1714-2 Preview", so well ahead of the 1.4.1106 version you're installing via `apt`. Release notes on that page include

> Support for the upcoming R 4.1.0 release, including the new |> pipe, (x) function shorthand, and new graphics engine.

Another alternative would be to *downgrade* R to an older version; for Windows the 4.0.5 binary appears to be available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.0.5/R-4.0.5-win.exe). Unfortunately, the [MacOS download page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) only appears to offer 3.6.3 in previous versions (not any 4.0.x releases) — which feels like a long way to downgrade.

Comment: What does "Preview" version mean? Is there something we should be aware of before installing this version?

Comment: Thanks Ben, do you know if that'll work for Ubuntu 20.04? I only see it going up to Ubuntu 18 on https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: "Preview" means it's a beta/unreleased version. It says somewhere the equivalent of "preview releases are usually stable, but be aware that this isn't an officially released version"

Comment: It installs OK on PopOS! 20.10; don't know if it will work for you or not. (I would guess the RStudio folks are rushing to get an official/fully supported release out ...)

Comment: Hm, it's telling me 'failed to install file: not supported'. Maybe I'll just downgrade my R version until Rstudio comes out with the full release.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04. I should stop ubuntu auto updating the R packages to prevent breaks like this in the future,

Comment: I also asked this question and was directed to Kevin Ushley's tweet. I ended up upgrading RStudio and so far I have not had any issues. I'm really liking the new native pipe operator "|>", which can be used interchangeably with dplyr's "%>%"

Comment: yeap, exactly the same problem yesterday - i spent half a day to figure out that i had to remove 4 and downgrade to 3.6 to make Rstudio and R workable again - hope this gets fixed soon!

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same issue and checked RStudio for an update. They now have, at the time of writing this, version 1.4.1717 for Debian/Ubuntu (I am running Ubuntu 20). Updating has fixed my ggplot issue with the same warnings.