# Problems with new R version

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I recently update my R version (R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen") and, from the first moment, I faced a problem with ggplot package. Everytime I call the ggplot function my R session aborts. I don't know why this happens. Please help me, I tried to uninstall RStudio and Reinstall it but nothing happens. When I use the R compiler, with no IDE, I have no problem, so I think it's a RStudio problem.

My Os id Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to reinstall ggplot but nothing changed. Do you think Rstudio will solve the bug in the next few days?

Comment: Have you already tried to reinstall or update ggplot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R crashing while displaying ggplot after update (process memory read out of range)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638836/r-crashing-while-displaying-ggplot-after-update-process-memory-read-out-of-rang)

Comment: This is a huge "oops", and one that RStudio has acknowledged and is rapidly patching. The preview version (which may be released any day now) should fix it. Try with https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ (v1.4.1716-3), and if it doesn't fix your issue, then this is either more of a bug for RStudio (in which case: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/), or is perhaps something new with your code, in which case we'd need to see that, too. (If that's the case, ping me here and I'll reopen the question.) Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans BTW, I am using the latest version of `Rstudio` and `R` and I have not experienced the issue yet. Is there an opinion why this may not affect my system?

Comment: What is your OS? I wonder if this is primarily windows and/or just not *your* OS. (Good point, though.) (Since I don't use RStudio regularly, I'm unable to really test ... and I'm on windows anyway, so almost certainly a problem for me :-)

Comment: My Os id Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to reinstall ggplot but nothing changed. Do you think Rstudio will solve the bug in the next few days?

Comment: @r2evans I am also on Windows and everything works fine. Interesting!

Comment: Federico, did you install the preview release of the RStudio IDE? I see that RStudio doesn't advertise for Ubuntu 20 yet, so you may need to follow the advice on https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-rstudio-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux to manually install the IDE version released for Ubuntu 18.